# Emitting events in Angular 1 from nested child components

Tags: angularjs

Working with Angular 1.5, and given a component hierarchy such as:

```
compA
  compB
    compC
```

Is there a better way to bubble events from nested child components to the interested parent component?

The two options I see are:

### Call `$scope.$emit()` from compC.  Use `$scope.$on()` in compA.

Pros

- compC is decoupled and more likely to be re-usable
- compB does not have to be made aware of this output in any way

Cons

- Use of $scope, which I was hoping to avoid since it no longer exists in NG2.  However, I'm not finding a better solution.

### Pass callback from compA to compB and then to compC using a `&` binding

Pros

- compC is decoupled and more likely to be re-usable

Cons

- compB has to be involved, making this solution fragile

Maybe I should make an exception and allow $scope use for this scenario.  Or, there is the option of emitting/listening on $rootScope instead.

EDIT: I'm finding $rootScope should be used only for truly global events, and it's common to forget to clean up your listeners, which is done automatically on $scope.

Answer (score 1):

One more way of passing data from `CompC` to `CompA` (or in between any components) would be to use a service instead of event based message passing. You could define dependency in all the components on a service and use that service to pass data amongs them. This would again make the components reusable.

Comment: That is another option and helps to promote reusability.  I've been investigating an implementation using the Flux pattern via alt.js and redux.